# Function with removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an exercise in stein: Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in the punctured disk around the origin, suppose also $|f(z)|\leq A|z|^{-1+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and all $z$ near 0. Show that $f$ has removable singularity at zero.

My goal is to show that $f$ is bounded. Any hints to show it is bounded? If $|z|<\delta$ for delta small, and $\epsilon>1$, then I cant obtain an upper bound for $f$.

Comment: Consider the function $g(z) = z\cdot f(z)$. Find out what you can say about that, then use what you found to answer the questions about $f$.

Comment: Thanks, $|g|\leq A|z|^\epsilon$ implies $g$ has a zero at $z=0$, and $g$ is holomorphic in the unit disk. So $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$ since the Taylor series has only nonnegative powers

Comment: Right. Would you mind converting that comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by $|z-z_{0}|$ to get $|(z-z_{0})(f(x))| \leq A |z-z_{0}|^{\epsilon}$. Now you just show that letting $z \rightarrow z_0$ demonstrates that $res_{z_{0}}(f)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong here.  $f(z) = 1/z$ satisfies this with $\epsilon = 2$.  Are you sure you've quoted the question correctly?

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake, now is fixed